# Excel macro to find between Sheets and properly format data

Tags: vba, excel, google-sheets

I will appreciate any of your help regarding this matter and hope that we can solve it.

Here is what I need:

Take a value from Sheet2 D1 and search for it in Sheet1 A column.

If value is found, let's say in A8 cell, then take a value from B8 (next to B8) and put it in Sheet2 D1 cell (overwrite the old value).

Visually:

Sheet2 D column:

```
A0933399489
A0933397000
A0933398000
A0933399000
```

Sheet1 A column:    Sheet1 B column:

```
A0933399489     0000000001
A0933397000     0000000002
56456584546     0000000003
A0933398000
23564598654     0000000004
A0933399000     0000000005
```

Take first value from Sheet2 D column: A0933399489
and search for it in Sheet1 A column
If found - copy appropriate Sheet1 B cell - in this case 0000000001
and paste it to Sheet2 D column cell - in this case A0933399489

- value to search is always starting with A09333*
- information in Sheet1 is not always nicely formatted, some of lines may contain random data

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO isn't intended to be a free code-writing service, but rather a resource to use when you have hit a stumbling block in whatever code you are currently working on.

Comment: Please include your current code and attempts

Comment: will add a code as soon as I'm home. thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the end goal of your sheet.  Do you need to overwrite Sheet2 column D?
A simple Vlookup could do the trick:
in sheet2 cell E1 = `=VLOOKUP(D1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)`